# Selenium > Web Drive : how to find a nested element by xpath (ruby)

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium

I have a nested <div>:

```
<div id="international-map">
 <div id='a'>
    <a> link a1 </a>
    <a> link a2 </a>
    <a> link a3 </a>
  </div>
  <div id='b'>
       <a> link b1 </a>
       <a> link b2 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get all the links under 'international-map'?

I tried  two approaches and failed :(

1. `div= @driver.find_element(:id => 'international-map')`
2. `e=@driver.find_elements(:xpath =>   "//div[@id='international-map']//div[@tag_name='a']")`

thank you (**even a C# and Java code**  helps)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay! You can also use `#css` or `#xpath` as below:

```
@driver.find_elements(:css,"div#international-map a").map(&:text)
# => [" link a1 ", " link a2 ", " link a3 ", " link b1 ", " link b2 "]
```

or

```
@driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//div[@id = 'international-map']//a").map(&:text)
# => [" link a1 ", " link a2 ", " link a3 ", " link b1 ", " link b2 "]
```

Comment: Is there some way to chain the find_element_* methods? I am trying to access a select element in a form so I want to do something like driver.find_element_by_tag_name("form").find_element_by_css_selector("number-of-people") but I got an error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct XPath expression is

```
//div[@id = 'international-map']//a/string()
```